# How to populate a matrix using two sets of criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I have a list of order numbers (Lets say 1001,1002,1003),a list of products (Let's say X,Y,Z) and a volume per product, per order. An order can contain product X and Y, or only product X, or product X,Y and Z. For each product in an order, there is a volume associated to it. I have three columns : 1. Order numbers, 2. Product 3. Volume. I have to create a matrix with order number on the Y-axis, Product on the X-axis and then populate the matrix with the volume based on the order number and product specified. Can anyone help me with some code in VBA or a formula that I can drag across and down the matrix to populate it?
I have a list of 1000+ products and 1000+ order numbers so it's going to be a huge matrix. Any help would be appreciated

I have tried countifs but I can't drag the formula horizontally and vertically to populate the whole table because I have to lock certain values for the horizontal drag, and others for the vertical drag.

Comment: Why don't you use a Pivot Table for this ? Goto `Select the Data then Insert > Pivot Table` .... Then drag the Order Numbers to `Columns` , Product to `Rows` & Volumes to `Values`.

Comment: I want to use the matrix to allocate orders and see which orders are filled based on total available stock. So after populating the matrix I want to add checkboxes in the far left column. Let's say for instance Order 1001 has 2 of product X, 5 of product Y and 10 of product Z, and in stock we have 10 of each product, I would like the order number to be highlighted in green. Then the dispatcher can tick the checkbox to "book" that order. So...I want to see the whole matrix if possible.

Comment: Did you try the Pivot ? you will get your matrix if you make a pivot out of the data. Then you can proceed with your checkboxes and other stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Mikku ! I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, not enough rep to comment. Feel free to tell me the good way to provide my 2 cents.)

If a pivot table is not an option (for instance whe you want to reprocess it afterwards), and your Excel version is not too old, you may also reach your purpose by using a simple Power Query script : `Data > From a Table`, and then in the Power Query editor, click the Product column, and then choose `Transform > Pivot Column`, and you're set:
[here's an illustration of the benefit of the Power Query way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy98w.png)